# increase height of react native text input and text on input push on bottom?

Tags: css, react-native

this is my code:

```
const StyledTextInput = styled.TextInput`
  background-color: red;
  font-family: SF Pro Text Regular;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000000;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  ${(props) =>
    props.error &&
    `
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
  `};
`;
```

basically what i am trying to do is increase height of text input but when it have text inside the text is in center, how do i make the text go on bottom?

Comment: Maybe you could try using increase [lineheight](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#lineheight) and [textAlignVertical](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#textalignvertical) to buttom?

Comment: line height works but that blinkng | is also affected, what you call that? can you decrease the height of that?

Comment: If you decrease that smaller than default, I think it may show incorrect to cut the word? Is `textAlignVertical`=`bottom` work?  I found I type the wrong word of bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a container to the TextInput and make that container act like the TextInput.

Also, use layout animation for a better experience.

[image]

## **Sample Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, LayoutAnimation, Platform, UIManager
} from 'react-native';

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
 if (UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental) {
   UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
 }
}

export default class Calls extends Component {
  state={ bigger: false }

  focus=() => {
    this.textInput.focus();
  }

  toggle=() => {
    const { bigger } = this.state;
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    this.setState({ bigger: !bigger });
  }

  render() {
    const { bigger } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.focus}
          style={[styles.inputContainer, { height: bigger ? 200 : 60 }]}
          activeOpacity={1}
        >
          <TextInput
            ref={(e) => { this.textInput = e; }}
            defaultValue="ASWIN"
            style={styles.input}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggle}>
          <Text style={styles.toggle}>Toggle</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' },
  inputContainer: {
    width: '90%', justifyContent: 'flex-end', borderWidth: 1,
  },
  input: {
    fontSize: 20, height: 50, width: '100%', padding: 0, paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  toggle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginTop: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#00000099',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    color: '#fff',
  },
});
```